# Symbols show as Loaded but still get “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.”

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I am encountering the “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” issue in Visual Studio 2017.

I have gone through a number of the posts on fixing “The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.” issue but nothing seems to work.

- The Symbol Status under Debug | Windows | Modules is "Symbols Loaded".
- I have cleaned and re-built the solution.
- [Define DEBUG constant] and [Define TRACE constant] are checked.
- [Debug Info:] is set to [full].
- Build configuration is set to Debug.
- Optimize code is Off.
- Deleted the PDB and did a Rebuild All.

I have found that if a programmatic breakpoint is added:

```
Debugger.Break()
```

normal breakpoints (set in Visual Studio) will be hit.  This may be bringing in missing debug symbols.  The problem I have with this explanation is that all Modules are showing as "Symbols Loaded" with and without the programmatic breakpoint.

Comment: Which kind of app did you really debug? Do you enable the Microsoft Symbol Servers under Tools->Options->Debugging->Symbols? Please also think about the .net framework version if it was the general C# project. In addition, please visit the output and Error list windows, maybe you could get some information there.

Comment: This is a console application.  The .Net Framework is 4.5.  Debugging actually worked earlier in the week without problem.  To determine possible causes, I am now focusing on what changed this week.

Comment: Do you get any latest information in your side? Maybe you could reset your VS settings, and then debug it again. Note: Not in release mode, just debug it in Debug mode. If you get any messages, please share it here.

Comment: No solution as of yet - I have asked another developer on my team to try this solution on his workstation.  I will post a solution if we find one.

Comment: Using a programmatic breakpoint such as: Debugger.Break(); does work. Just need to remove this prior to release.  So far, no luck at all on approaches mention in this and other questions on this exchange.  Other developers have tried the same solution and have the same issue with breakpoints.  If we find a solution, I will post it.

Comment: Could you delete the previous symbols files downloaded from Microsoft Servers under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols? Generally it has the default cache folder, please clean up or change it to another folder, how about the result? Please also try to run your VS as the admin, view the result.